# How can I sort an array of strings?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of input words separated by comma.  I want to sort these words by alphabetical and length.  How can I do this without using the built-in sorting functions?

Comment: How would you like them to be sorted? Alphabetically? By the length of the string? Or else what?

Comment: Why (other than homework) would you want to do this without using any built-in functions?

Comment: @Jon ... Perhaps because knowing how to implement a sorting routine is the first step in learning how to design your own algorithms. Concert pianists don't generally play "Mary Had a Little Lamb" for an audience, but that's how most people started learning.

Comment: :-) to practice on the doing functions i already made  (1st: to capitalise the first letter from each word ,2ed reverse order .... and more ... but I'm stuck i made some research on the net but i still wont find it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question!! Sorting is probably the most important concept to learn as an up-and-coming computer scientist.

There are actually lots of different algorithms for sorting a list.

When you break all of those algorithms down, the most fundamental operation is the comparison of two items in the list, defining their "natural order".

For example, in order to sort a list of integers, I'd need a function that tells me, given any two integers X and Y whether X is less than, equal to, or greater than Y.

For your strings, you'll need the same thing: a function that tells you which of the strings has the "lesser" or "greater" value, or whether they're equal.

Traditionally, these "comparator" functions look something like this:

```
int CompareStrings(String a, String b) {
   if (a < b)
      return -1;
   else if (a > b)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

I've left out some of the details (like, how do you compute whether a is less than or greater than b? clue: iterate through the characters), but that's the basic skeleton of any comparison function. It returns a value less than zero if the first element is smaller and a value greater than zero if the first element is greater, returning zero if the elements have equal value.

But what does that have to do with sorting?

A sort routing will call that function for pairs of elements in your list, using the result of the function to figure out how to rearrange the items into a sorted list. The comparison function defines the "natural order", and the "sorting algorithm" defines the logic for calling and responding to the results of the comparison function.

Each algorithm is like a big-picture strategy for guaranteeing that ANY input will be correctly sorted. Here are a few of the algorithms that you'll probably want to know about:

**Bubble Sort:**

Iterate through the list, calling the comparison function for all adjacent pairs of elements. Whenever you get a result greater than zero (meaning that the first element is larger than the second one), swap the two values. Then move on to the next pair. When you get to the end of the list, if you didn't have to swap ANY pairs, then congratulations, the list is sorted! If you DID have to perform any swaps, go back to the beginning and start over. Repeat this process until there are no more swaps.

NOTE: this is usually not a very efficient way to sort a list, because in the worst cases, it might require you to scan the whole list as many as N times, for a list with N elements.

***Merge Sort:***

This is one of the most popular divide-and-conquer algorithms for sorting a list. The basic idea is that, if you have two already-sorted lists, it's easy to merge them. Just start from the beginning of each list and remove the first element of whichever list has the smallest starting value. Repeat this process until you've consumed all the items from both lists, and then you're done!

```
1     4        8     10    
   2     5  7     9
------------ becomes ------------> 
1  2  4  5  7  8  9  10
```

But what if you don't have two sorted lists? What if you have just one list, and its elements are in random order?

That's the clever thing about merge sort. You can break any single list into smaller pieces, each of which is either an unsorted list, a sorted list, or a single element (which, if you thing about it, is actually a sorted list, with length = 1).

So the first step in a merge sort algorithm is to divide your overall list into smaller and smaller sub lists, At the tiniest levels (where each list only has one or two elements), they're very easy to sort. And once sorted, it's easy to merge any two adjacent sorted lists into a larger sorted list containing all the elements of the two sub lists.

NOTE: This algorithm is ***much*** better than the bubble sort method, described above, in terms of its worst-case-scenario efficiency. I won't go into a detailed explanation (which involves some fairly trivial math, but would take some time to explain), but the quick reason for the increased efficiency is that this algorithm breaks its problem into ideal-sized chunks and then merges the results of those chunks. The bubble sort algorithm tackles the whole thing at once, so it doesn't get the benefit of "divide-and-conquer".

---

Those are just two algorithms for sorting a list, but there are a lot of other interesting techniques, each with its own advantages and disadvantages: Quick Sort, Radix Sort, Selection Sort, Heap Sort, Shell Sort, and Bucket Sort.

The internet is overflowing with interesting information about sorting. Here's a good place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms

Comment: +1 for providing valuable content without providing "cut & paste" solution

Answer (score 3):

Create a console application and paste this into the Program.cs as the body of the class.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string [] strList = "a,b,c,d,e,f,a,a,b".Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach(string s in strList.Sort())
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}

public static string [] Sort(this string [] strList)
{
    return strList.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
}
```

Notice that I do use a built in method, [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx).  As other answers point out there are many different sort algorithms you could implement there and I think my code snippet does everything for you except the actual sort algorithm.

[Some C# specific sorting tutorials](http://www.publicjoe.f9.co.uk/csharp/sort00.html)

Comment: The OP wants to write a sorting algorithm rather than using a built-in.

Comment: what does  "this string [] strList"  mean?

Comment: Raymond, I know. It is it's own function though :).  Sara can fill out the body of that extension method with her own sort implementation and she will be good to go.  I didn't want to do all the work.

Comment: Raymond, I updated to specify why I used a built in function.

Answer (score 2):

There is an entire area of study built around [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).  You may want to choose a simple one and implement it.

Though it won't be the most performant, it shouldn't take you too long to implement a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use build-in-functions, you have to create one by your self. I would recommend *Bubble sort* or some similar algorithm. Bubble sort is not an effective algoritm, but it get the works done, and is easy to understand.

You will find much good reading on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: wikipedia is blocked in my country

Comment: Wow which country is that? China?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a wiki for quicksort.

Still not sure why you don't want to use the built in sort?

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort damages the brain.

Insertion sort is at least as simple to understand and code, and is actually useful in practice (for very small data sets, and nearly-sorted data). It works like this:

Suppose that the first n items are already in order (you can start with n = 1, since obviously one thing on its own is "in the correct order").

Take the (n+1)th item in your array. Call this the "pivot". Starting with the nth item and working down:
   - if it is bigger than the pivot, move it one space to the right (to create a "gap" to the left of it).
   - otherwise, leave it in place, put the "pivot" one space to the right of it (that is, in the "gap" if you moved anything, or where it started if you moved nothing), and stop.

Now the first n+1 items in the array are in order, because the pivot is to the right of everything smaller than it, and to the left of everything bigger than it. Since you started with n items in order, that's progress.

Repeat, with n increasing by 1 at each step, until you've processed the whole list.

This corresponds to one way that you might physically put a series of folders into a filing cabinet in order: put one in; then put another one into its correct position by pushing everything that belongs after it over by one space to make room; repeat until finished. Nobody ever sorts physical objects by bubble sort, so it's a mystery to me why it's considered "simple".

All that's left now is that you need to be able to work out, given two strings, whether the first is greater than the second. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "alphabetical and length" : alphabetical order is done by comparing one character at a time from each string. If there not the same, that's your order. If they are the same, look at the next one, unless you're out of characters in one of the strings, in which case that's the one that's "smaller".

Answer (score 0):

**Use NSort**

I ran across the [NSort](http://www.projectdistributor.net/Projects/Project.aspx?projectId=108) library a couple of years ago in the book [Windows Developer Power Tools](http://www.windevpowertools.com).  The NSort library implements a number of sorting algorithms.  The main advantage to using something like NSort over writing your own sorting is that is is already tested and optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Posting link to fast string sort code in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/fast_string_sort.aspx

Another point:
The suggested comparator above is not recommended for non-English languages:

int CompareStrings(String a, String b) {
if (a < b)       return -1;
else if (a > b)
return 1;    else
return 0; }

Checkout this link for non-English language sort:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688122

And as mentioned, use nsort for really gigantic arrays that don't fit in memory.